# SQL order by statement

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to learn sql and I have a question. How can I order the output by the logical order of the days? For example I want the persons to be ordered with the HIREDAY from 'Monday' to 'Sunday'.

```
select first_name,
TO_CHAR(hire_date,'Day') as "HIREDAY"
from employees
order by HIREDAY;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Daniel  Friday   
Ismael  Friday    
Gerald  Monday   
Renske  Monday   
Jason   Monday   
Vance   Saturday 
Jenni   Saturday 
Michael Saturday 
John    Sunday   
James   Sunday   
Matthew Sunday   
Payam   Thursday 
Irene   Thursday 
Michael Tuesday  
Kevin   Tuesday  
Anthony Wednesday
Karen   Wednesday
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a `case` statement:

```
order by (case when trim(Hire_Day) = 'Monday' then 1
               when trim(Hire_Day) = 'Tuesday' then 2
               when trim(Hire_Day) = 'Wednesday' then 3
               when trim(Hire_Day) = 'Thursday' then 4
               when trim(Hire_Day) = 'Friday' then 5
               when trim(Hire_Day) = 'Saturday' then 6
               when trim(Hire_Day) = 'Sunday' then 7
          end)
```

In Oracle, you can also use `DAYOFWEEK()`:

```
order by DAYOFWEEK(hire_date)
```

Or
    order by to_char(Hire_Day, 'D')

Comment: I am using oracle but it doesn't recognize weekday()

Comment: @Theo . . . It is well documented in Oracle (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday), and I'm pretty sure it has been in many past versions.

Comment: And one more thing, the case statement doesn't order the days correctly... I can't figure why

Comment: It's not ordering correctly because each day is left padded with spaces on every day but Wednesday because the `fm` modifier should be used.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me what should I do so I could get a correct output?

Comment: @Ben . . . Thank you; I provided one revision that fixes the problem.  I realize that I usually use `dy`, which doesn't have this issue at all.

Comment: You can use Gordon's edit @Theo, or you can alter your original query to `to_char(hire_date,'fmDay')`, which will remove the space. Or, as Gordon says use the 3 character day instead (or my answer in the duplicate I suggested, which doesn't rely on characters at all).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
select first_name to_char((hire_date),'fmD') "Day"
from employees
order by "Day";

In this you'll get correct order of days in number. In your case from to_char name of days were alphabetically being ordered which is not required.

Comment: This won't necessarily order Monday first, as I explain in the duplicate... (the `fm` isn't necessary either).